# python smallest data type for socket chatter

Tags: python, sockets, types, byte

What is the smallest "packet" one can send via the socket module? I only need to send 16 bits of data, 2 bytes and it is something I have to send rapidly so I would like it as small as possible. I have done some "experiments" to find the smallest size, nothing I get is less than 28 bytes.

Test Results:

```
sys.getsizeof(2) = 28

sys.getsizeof(0b0001) = 28

sys.getsizeof(bytes(0b0001)) = 34

sys.getsizeof('0001') = 66

sys.getsizeof('a') = 60

sys.getsizeof(0b0001000100010001000100010001) = 28

sys.getsizeof(0b000100010001000100010001000100010001) = 32
```

I am just wondering if that is indeed the smallest I can send.

---

I also want to add that python is very hard to work with binary. I know it isn't as relevant as it once was but for some things it is handy. I say this for two reasons:

1) I can't seem to keep a variable binary, it always reverts back to integer or another type.

2) Upon testing I did a binary to byte conversion and got this as a size:

```
sys.getsizeof(bytes(0b0001001001001001001001001)) = 2396778
```

Comment: these are system dependent values on my system `sizeof('a') = 25` and `sizeof(2) = 12

Comment: So is there anyway to force a socket to take only two bits?

Answer (score 3):

`sys.getsizeof` returns the interal size of a Python int, not a C int.  You can use `struct.pack` to get the C bytes:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('H',32768)  # default endian-ness
'\x00\x80'
>>> struct.pack('>H',32768)  # force big-endian
'\x80\x00'
```

To send two explicit bytes:

```
>>> struct.pack('BB',100,200)
'd\xc8'
```

Note that the bytes are represented in a string.  `'d'` is the ASCII character for 100 and `\xc8` is hexadecimal notation for 200:

```
>>> ord('d')
100
>>> 0xc8
200
```

You can get the resulting size of a packet created with `.pack`.  For example, the size of two shorts and a long:

```
>>> struct.calcsize('>HHL')
8
```

See the [struct module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html?highlight=struct#struct).

Comment: Great!  If an answer is acceptable click the green check to the left.  Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the second part of your question:

"binary" is a representation of an integer, not a type. You can use `bin()` to get a binary representation as a string. You can convert the binary string representation to an `int` using.... `int()`. e.g.

```
>>> x = 1234
>>> bin(x)
'0b10011010010'     # note, this is a string
>>> print int(bin(x), 2)
1234
```

For the second part I think that you must be mistaken:

```
>>> bytes(0b0001001001001001001001001)
'2396745'
>>> sys.getsizeof(bytes(0b0001001001001001001001001))
44
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of bytes that are sent across a socket depends on a lot more than the size of a data value in a programming language.  For example, sending a single byte across a new TCP connection to "www.google.com:80"  results in the following packet flow:

```
A->B: 64 byte TCP SYN
B->A: 60 byte TCP SYN+ACK
A->B: 52 byte TCP ACK
A->B: 53 byte TCP packet containing a single byte payload
B->A: 52 byte TCP ACK
A->B: 52 byte TCP FIN
B->A: 52 byte TCP FIN+ACK
A->B: 52 byte TCP FIN
```

So that is a total of 437 bytes to send a single byte payload.  UDP is a little more forgiving resulting in only 29 bytes sent for a single byte payload.  You can squeeze the payload down to 21 bytes if you use a raw socket.

In any case, reducing the number of bytes in the payload to 1 and using a minimal protocol (e.g., UDP in most cases) is about as good as you will get.  The key sizes are:

```
IP Header = 20 bytes
IP Header + UDP Header = 20 + 8 = 28 bytes
IP Header + TCP Header = 20 + 20 = 40 bytes
```

All of the various networking protocols limit the number of payload bytes to whole bytes.

Another thing to remember is that below the IP header, you have whatever the underlying physical layer is.  In the case of standard Ethernet, you end up with everything getting chunked up into 1500 byte packets.  Doesn't matter if you send 1 byte or 1000 bytes, you end up sending 1500 bytes on the wire.  Of course this is a massive over simplification, but the idea should have sunk in -- if you are operating on standard Ethernet then I wouldn't worry much about sending a few bytes.  Limit your usage to UDP if you do not need acknowledgements.

If you are really interested, pick up a copy of the hallowed [TCP/IP Illustrated](http://www.kohala.com/start/) series.